# How to enable systemd on WSL2: Ubuntu 20 and CentOS 8

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, systemd, init, systemctl

I'm on WSL2 (Windows Subsystem for Linux, v2) and got the CentOS 8 WSL from:
https://github.com/yuk7/CentWSL

And the Ubuntu 20 WSL downloaded from Windows Store has no `systemd` enabled too.

Got it run as usual, however, `systemd` is not running, although it does exist in the file system:

```
$ cat /etc/*-release | grep NAME
NAME="CentOS Linux"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 8 (Core)"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:8"

$ stat /lib/systemd/systemd
  File: /lib/systemd/systemd
  Size: 2523648         Blocks: 4936       IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 2h/2d   Inode: 1407374884100769  Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2020-05-31 13:17:53.497597100 +0700
Modify: 2020-04-10 04:52:32.000000000 +0700
Change: 2020-05-30 12:06:52.791586300 +0700
 Birth: -

$ systemctl
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

`/sbin/init` is already a symbolic link to `systemd`:

```
$ stat /sbin/init
  File: /sbin/init -> ../lib/systemd/systemd
  Size: 22              Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
Device: 2h/2d   Inode: 2251799814381086  Links: 1
Access: (0777/lrwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2020-04-10 04:52:20.000000000 +0700
Modify: 2020-04-10 04:52:20.000000000 +0700
Change: 2020-05-30 12:06:53.461589000 +0700
 Birth: -
```

I found 2 init files:

```
/init
/sbin/init --> /lib/systemd/systemd
```

Possibly WSL2 Linux kernel loads `/init` instead of `/sbin/init`?

How to enable `systemd` in this distro, for daemons like sshd, nginx, etc. to run? Need to touch `/sbin/init` or that kind of file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have a work-around here but it doesn't work for those services explicitly require systemd:

Still using `/init` instead of `/sbin/init` on WSL2, works for regular services, not those explicitly require 'systemd'.

Find out where systemctl is:

`which systemctl`

Use the path to systemctl for the following commands.

Install Python 2 (if not available by default):

```
sudo dnf install python2 -y
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python
```

Wrap systemctl in Python (or somehow let systemctl work with systemd not on PID 1):

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/systemctl /usr/bin/systemctl.old
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement/master/files/docker/systemctl.py >temp
sudo mv temp /usr/bin/systemctl
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/systemctl
```

Test systemctl:

```
sudo dnf install nginx -y
sudo systemctl start nginx
curl localhost
sudo systemctl stop nginx
```

Answer (score 7):

The systemd-genie https://github.com/arkane-systems/genie is recommended for every distro supported and endorsed by systemd.io. It works both in the system (systemd --system) and user mode (systemd --user). t is well maintained and easy for integration with wsl and Windows terminal. No additional scripts are needed.

Answer (score 5):

I found this to be helpful:

- https://github.com/DamionGans/ubuntu-wsl2-systemd-script NOTE: This no longer works

  1. Script to install required tools
  2. Script to start systemd in separate namespace
  3. Script to run script in systemd namespace
- https://github.com/arkane-systems/genie

  - Almost same ideology, but as single binary.

  - Requires DotNet
  - Requires machined (i.e. not working on CentOS7)

Comment: "it should be self-explanatory." - It isn't, care to explain?

Comment: @Ramhound I apologise I didn't mean to sound arrogant. The readme files explained it quite well, so I figured not do it again. Which part are you having issues with.

Comment: The links might disappear, it's always a good practice to share all the information here and when that's not possible to give a brief explanation.

Comment: I am kinda new to this, so didn't know that, will try to stick to it in the future. Thanks for the info

Comment: Careful with that first link. Seems the script do doesn't work on recent versions, and the maintainer has archived the repo.

Answer (score 1):

Now `wsl` takes care of `systemd` natively: see [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/systemd-support-is-now-available-in-wsl/)

Comment: that's nice, maybe mongodb can run inside WSL now

Comment: Maybe you could accept my answer?