# GUI for WSL2 CentOS through RDP

Tags: centos, gui, wsl2

I've installed an `Xfce` desktop for `WSL2` `Ubuntu-18.04-LTS` through `xrdp` with relative ease, but am having difficulty with `CentOS 7`.

I have used the workaround [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1556609/how-to-enable-systemd-on-wsl2-ubuntu-20-and-centos-8) for `systemctl`. Afterwards, I've tried following [this](https://draculaservers.com/tutorials/install-xrdp-centos/) to get `xrpd` and `xfce` up and running.

I get to the login screen for `Xvnc`, but when I enter my username and credentials, it hangs for a few seconds and does nothing. Can someone help me get this working? Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Currently, I run

```
sudo systemctl start graphical.target
sudo systemctl start xrdp
```

I use port `3390` and when I run `localhost:3390` in `Windows Remote Desktop Connection`, I get the login screen:

[image: Login]

When I enter my credentials and try to log in, then I notice my cursor changes and the remote desktop header bar changes to `localhost`, but there are no desktop items:

[image: localhost-3390]

The steps I have executed are as follows:

1. Install `CentOS 7.9` from [zip asset on GitHub](https://github.com/mishamosher/CentOS-WSL/releases/tag/7.9-2009)
2. Perform a `sudo yum update && sudo yum upgrade -y`
3. Install the following packages

```
sudo yum install -y epel-release xrdp
sudo yum gropuinstall -y "Xfce"
sudo reboot
```

4. Configure `~/.Xclients`

```
#!/bin/bsh
XFCE="$(which xfce4-session 2>/dev/null)"
exec "$XFCE"
```

5. Perform the `systemctl` workaround

```
sudo dnf install python2 -y
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python
sudo mv /usr/bin/systemctl /usr/bin/systemctl.old
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement/master/files/docker/systemctl.py >temp
sudo mv temp /usr/bin/systemctl
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/systemctl
```

6. Configure `/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini` to use `port=3390`
7. Copy and paste `startwm.sh` to `/etc/xrdp`, replace last line with `startxfce4` (commenting out `xfce`), and `chmod +x` on it (see [here](https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/commit/85840863da78476f1d269c2b2b8f54d5e6471da0) for script).
8. Add username and password

```
useradd my-username
passwd my-passwd
```

9. Start `graphical.target` and `xrdp`

```
sudo systemctl enable xrdp
sudo systemctl enable graphical.target
sudo systemctl start graphical.target
sudo systemctl start xrdp
```

10. Log into `Windows Remote Desktop Connection` at `localhost:3390`

Comment: Have you configured Xvnc to start any kind of DE/session?

Comment: @TomYan Thanks for the reply! I have not. I think I tried that once, but didn't do it again. I'm also not sure of all the commands I should issue and in what order. e.g. Should I run `start graphical.target, start xrdp.session, start xrdp`?

Comment: @TomYan Okay, I configured a session, but I still get the same result (see updated question)